# This webpage has a redirect loop and SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, http-status-code-301

I am trying to setup proper 301 redirects for SEO via .htaccess and have had success redirecting the entire website's page URL's to an https:// version. However this rule:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.mydomain.com/
```

Gives me: "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Rewrite rules such as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Do not give me proper 301s just rewrites.

Comment: Your rule should be working. Did you remove `Redirect` directive ? Because it's because of it you have a redirect loop. Why do you want to add/keep it since your last rule should be working ? Also, clear your browser's cache before trying again (or try it with another browser)

Comment: Hey Justin, sorry. I hadn't included the last line. Yeah, each browser gives me a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only put this code in your htaccess, this should be working (clear your browser's cache or try with another because 301 redirects may be in cache)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

You said:

> Do not give me proper 301s just rewrites.

That's because you used `R` flag alone (which gives a 302 by default).

Comment: I don't know why my rule wasn't working but this fixes everything! Thanks. Any advice on images loaded with http:// ?

Comment: Each url redirects (if `http`) to `https` equivalent. Must be the same  behaviour for images. Otherwise, i guess you have other rules that makes collision